# SVG Draw Not working On chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, svg, draw

I'm writing a code to drawing svg single path with SCSS and it's working fine on firefox. but it's not working on google chrome. I'd be thankful if you have a way to this be a cross browser. 
Here is my CSS:

```
svg path, svg polygon {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: #1F1F1F;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 3319;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3319;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;



 -webkit-fill-opacity: 0;
  -webkit-stroke: #1F1F1F;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 0.5;
  -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 3319;
  -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 3319;
  -webkit-animation-name: draw;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

}
/* line 38, ../sass/screen.scss */
svg #Shadows__x28_positive_x29_ path, svg #Shadows__x28_positive_x29_ polygon {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes draw {
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    fill-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-width: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0
  }
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. It was because of @-webkit-keyframes here is the Resolved CSS:

```
    svg path, svg polygon {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  fill:asdasd #fff !important;
  stroke: #1F1F1F;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 3319;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3319;
  animation-name: draw;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;



 -webkit-fill-opacity: 0;
  -webkit-stroke: #1F1F1F;
  -webkit-stroke-width: 0.5;
  -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 3319;
  -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 3319;
  -webkit-animation-name: draw;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

}
/* line 38, ../sass/screen.scss */
svg #Shadows__x28_positive_x29_ path, svg #Shadows__x28_positive_x29_ polygon {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes draw {
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    fill-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-width: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    fill-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-width: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    -webkit-stroke-width: 0
  }
}
```

and it works fine :)